# Takes time to resume application from background, shows splash screen

Tags: iphone, ios

Our application takes time to resume from background in iPod, so it shows splash screen each time. When app enters foreground, it load some data from cache, if there is large amount of data it takes time. How can I handle this situation? I just put those methods into dispatch queue, but no remarkable effects.

Comment: What do you mean by it takes time so it shows splash screen?  Are you manually showing a splash screen or is the splash screen shown automatically?  If its automatic, its not because it takes time, its because the application was killed some time during back grounding to make room for other memory needs.

Comment: Splash screen is displayed automatically. Actually app won't exit, but it takes time to resume. On time profiling using instruments, those methods loading data from cache seems to be taking time to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a dispatch queue and send those time consuming methods (methods loading data from cache) to background. and when its done, and say you need to do some UI update now, get the main queue and update the UI there

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("name for the queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    //your extensive code goes here, should not involve any UI updates
    //If there are any UI updates involved, uncomment the following code:
    /*dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //UI update here, as it should always be done on main thread
    });*/
});
```

Since you are doing heavy computing on the main thread during launch, you are being shown the splash screen. you should take care of it and move it to background, as in future, if the loading from cache takes a long time, more than 10 secs, your application will be killed by the watchdog.

Cheers, have fun